# RESTful web service not getting correct request from c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, httpclient

i have created a c# client to consume my REST web service.

I have tested the web service method using SOAPUI and it works with the following request

```
POST http://example.com/RestServiceImpl.svc/CallADSWebMethod HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 12
Host: localhost:35798
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

{"test": "2"}
```

However i cannot produce the same httppost from my client application.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();       
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "2"));

HttpClient client = GetHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://example.com/RestServiceImpl.svc/CallADSWebMethod");
request.SetHeader("content-type", "application/json");

UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
request.SetEntity(formEntity);

HttpResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I used svctrace to check the service logs and the error message i see is

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'CallADSWebMethod'. Encountered unexpected character 't'.

Does anyone have any idea where i'm going wrong with this HttpPost Request?

Comment: ok so i added 

request.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(new StringEntity("{\"test\": \"2\"}", "UTF8"));

and the results display correctly, does anyone know a better way to format the json instead of adding it to a string manually?

Comment: well, you can serialize your object as json format. Have a look at [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UrlEncodedFormEntity` does not serialize the data in JSON format, which is what you want. You have a few options:

- Use the `JavaScriptSerializer` as @minhcat_vo suggested, or any other JSON serializers, including `DataContractJsonSerializer` (which happens to be the one used by WCF), JSON.NET, or any other. Then use the serialized string tand use a `StringEntity` as you're doing. However, you will likely not get a JSON object if you start with a `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` class. Try using a dictionary instead.
- You can also use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class and use a `StringContent` object with the same content.
- If you use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` you can also use an [`ObjectContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.objectcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) with a [`JsonMediaTypeFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.jsonmediatypeformatter%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), which will take your object and serialize it with the given formatter (in your case, JSON).

The code below shows one option:

```
var c = new HttpClient();
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Post,
    "http://example.com/RestServiceImpl.svc/CallADSWebMethod");
var body = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
body.AddProperty("test", "2");
req.Content = new StringContent(body.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var resp = await c.SendAsync(req);
```